# Equally generate a real number?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, real-numbers

When learning probability my professor wrote on the board:

"In general if $J$ in or equal $R^n$ then we can equally generate a point from J Such that:
P(A)=|A|/|J|
This is true if $0<|J|<\infty$

And, in particular, we can't a equally generate a general real number."

Can someone explain how we got the second conclusion? and why it's in particular?

Comment: I do not understand the statement of your professor.  Did you write it correctly?

Comment: The first statement states that the property of a multivariate uniform distribution. The second statement states that a the support of a uniform distribution cannot be an unbounded set, like a real number line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect there are some translation issues here. I believe what your professor said was, in English (and with a small clarification on the notation: $P(A) \equiv P(x \in A)$):

> If $J \subseteq \Bbb R^n$, then we can uniformly generate random points $x$ so that $$P(x \in A) = \frac {|A|}{|J|}$$ if and only if $0 < |J| < \infty$. In particular, we cannot uniformly generate a random real number.

As BGM states, the condition that $P(x \in A) = \frac {|A|}{|J|}$ is the definition of a uniform distribution: the probability of picking a number from a set is proportional to the size of that set. In this case, size refers to measure: $|A|$ is the $n$-dimensional volume of the set $A$. But obviously, the entire concept breaks down when $|J|$ is infinite, as then you are dividing by $\infty$, and for any $A$, will get either $0$ or an indefinite form.

The conclusion is "In particular" because it refers to specific case when $n = 1$ and $J = \Bbb R$. Because $|J| = \infty$, there is no way to define uniformity in this situation.

Comment: That makes sense, but how may I prove both claims?

Comment: Exactly what claims are you referring to?